# Cant load Android Emulator on Android studio

Tags: java, android, windows

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Go to AVD Manager-> Edit your AVD-> Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option-> Click Finish (Save)-> Start AVD again.

Try it once, it may be helpful to you!!